# System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection does not contain definition for 'Cast'

Tags: azure, x509certificate2, azure-hdinsight

I'm trying to create a MapReduce job using [HDInsight .NET SDK tutorial](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/hdinsight/submit-hadoop-jobs-programmatically/#mapreduce-sdk).

In creating the `JobSubmissionCertificateCredential` object, specifically the following line:

`X509Certificate2 cert = store.Certificates.Cast<X509Certificate2>().First(item => item.FriendlyName == certfriendlyname);`

I'm getting the following **error**: 'System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and no extension method 'Cast' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have...

- `using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;` at the top of my class.
- ran `Install-Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.HDInsight`

Anyone know of any updates to this block of code that gets the `Cast` working? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have `System.Linq` in your `using`s?

Comment: That was it! Can you answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cast<T>` is part of the `Enumerable` type located in the `System.Linq` namespace.  Add a reference to that namespace and you'll be good.